# Aggregate usage stats by user

Tags: monitoring, htop

I'd like to look at the aggregated usage information at a user level.

Basically hoping for a tool similar to `htop` but with the option to sum up all the processes for a user, for every user.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want psacct (or acct on some systems). It will provide:

- ac command prints the statistics of user logins/logouts (connect time) in hours.
- lastcomm command prints the information of previously executed commands of user.
- accton commands is used to turn on/off process for accounting.
- sa command summarizes information of previously executed commands.
- last and lastb commands show listing of last logged in users.

Install with

```
yum install psacct
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install acct
```

you then have to start the service

```
chkconfig psacct on
/etc/init.d/psacct start
```

Then you can use commands...

display total login time of each user

```
ac -p
```

display total of a user user

```
ac user
```

sa will give ps like usage stats... like

```
sa -m
```

and

```
sa -c
```

for processes and cpu minutes (this is the one you may be interested in).

I am not 100% sure if you want 100% htop compatible output, which is not what those will give you, but if you want stats like previous processes, percentages and usage, those two (out of all of those commands) will get you very close.

Most of that info was pulled [from this article](https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-monitor-user-activity-with-psacct-or-acct-tools/).

Comment: This looks great. but I'm not able to use `sa` without sudo permissions. `ac` works great though.